# Find all files which names have prefixes in a list?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

There is the following array.

```
$prefixes = 'abcdef, 123', 'xyx4, 222', 'bcde123$abc', .....
```

How to find all the files which name prefixes are in the list under a folder? (include the sub-folders)

Comment: Get the substring consisting of the first three letters of the file name. See if the array -contains that string.

Answer (score 3):

One option:

```
$prefixes = @(
'abc', 
'123',
'xyx',
'222',
'bcde'
) 

 [regex]$Prefix_Match = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($prefixes |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

 Get-ChildItem -Path '<folder root path>' -Recurse -File |
  where-object {$_.name -match $Prefix_Match}
```

Comment: The prefixes have `$`, `.` etc., which will confuse the regular expression.

Comment: {[regex]::escape($_)} should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-ChildItem`, and `[regex]::escape()` on your array elements while adding a wildcard to the `-Filter` parameter.

For example:

```
$array = @("file$1","file2")
foreach($element in $array) {
   Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Filter ([regex]::escape($element) + "*") -Recurse -File
}
```

will find all files in the folder `c:\temp` and subfolders that begin with `file$1` and `file2`